# add avatar in AbstractUser and Django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

My code works fine and I do migration to add avatar to my user.

But when I signup, avatar field does not show.

this is my code:
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


def get_path_name(instance, filename):
    path = 'media/avatar/'
    name = instance.user.id + "-" + instance.user.email
    path = path + name
    return path

# custom User model
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to= get_path_name, blank=True, null=True)
```

my form:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django import forms

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'avatar')

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            # validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 100
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Please use an image that is '
                    '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

            # validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                                            'GIF or PNG image.')

            # validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'avatar')

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            # validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 100
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Please use an image that is '
                    '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

            # validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                                            'GIF or PNG image.')

            # validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar
```

my template:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}

{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

What I had missed as my sign up page is like that without avatar?
[image]

I tried to add field in template but seems not working. When I go to admin site I don t see avatar field but migrations had been done...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my answer . Add this in settings.py

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'